# Latest update doesn't boot on my computer

Tags: release-freya, boot, graphic-drivers, updates

So I updated my computer last night, and restarted it and was stuck on a black screen. After waiting about 15 minutes and restarting my computer a couple of times, I finally unplugged it, hoping to solve it in the morning. By booting in recovery mode for the latest update the best I could see on the screen is in the photo I posted below.
[image: Elementary IO Boot Failed]

Finally I got my system up-and-running again, but in a previous variant of Elementary IO. And every time I start my computer I now have to go through this screen.
[image: Elementary IO Recover Doesn't Work]

While I in recover mode, it said that my graphic drivers might not be supported. I had a major issue with graphic drivers when I first installed the OS. I feel like this is something that needs to be fixed in another update of Elementary IO.

Did anyone else have issues like this with the latest update?
Does anyone have a solution that might prevent this from happening again?

System Specs) MoBo: Asrock Z87-M8| CPU: i5-4570S| GPU: GTX 750 Ti

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any USB devices plugged into your computer when you booted? If you do, pull **ALL** of them out and try rebooting.

Elementary is based of of the Ubuntu kernel. Graphics support for Intel 4600 was added in the [13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310341/do-graphics-drivers-for-intel-hd-4600-exist) version of the kernel. What elementary were you getting the USB error in, and which version did you restore back to?

You may want to try installing from the latest iso file from the elementary website [here](http://elementary.io/). Post back if it installs error free, or if you get similar errors.

The second picture you posted is of GRUB, the GRand Unified Bootloader. This is the software that actually loads the operating system. If you had other operating systems, then they would show up in that menu.

If you would like to hide the menu, boot into your install, open a terminal window, and type:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/grub
```

Then set the GRUB_TIMEOUT and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT lines to 0.
Afterwards, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Cheers,
~Kisa

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem 2 weeks ago...
Just enter "recovery mode" and choose "Repair dpkg files" and "Check files system" and then restart.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Select one of your old kernel's recovery mode and open shell or terminal and type `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0.31-generic`.I have used the new kernel with my PC and had no problems (maybe your hardware is incompatible) although I decided to upgrade to Linux Kernel 4.2.